# Vault: Data synchronisation between a cloud and an on-premise instanz?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Can hashicorp vault be configured so that there is an instance in the cloud and an instance on an on-premise computer? Both vaults should regularly synchronize their data / secrets.
What are the mechanisms here?

The use case is that the on-premise computer is not constantly connected to the internet. The applications on the internal network should be able to connect to other applications using the stored vault secrets of the on-premise server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashicorp Vault provides replication in Vault Enterprise. Multi-datacenter deployments is one of usage scenarios. The setup you are looking for is primary (cloud) / seconday (on-prem) in your case. More info: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/enterprise/replication